# (MIGRATE on RUBY) rake aborted! VERSION is required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I tried to migrate some command to database from ubuntu terminal.

Here's my terminal code:

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION = 20140523041349
```

And this my migrate file code:

```
class Problem9 < ActiveRecord::Migration
def up
add_column :articles, :rating, :integer
change_column :users, :address, :text
rename_column :articles, :body, :description
end
def down
end
end
```

It appear the error like this:

```
rake aborted!
VERSION is required
/home/delta7/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:229:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate:up
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space in your argument, like so:

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20140523041349
```

Rake is pretty picky. You may also need to prefix with `bundle exec` if working on multiple projects with multiple versions of rake:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20140523041349
```

Comment: Try running `bundle exec rake db:migrate:status | grep 20140523041349`. If it says "up" for this migration then Rails has marked this version number as having already been run and that is why it did nothing this time. It should say "down" if it hasn't been run already. So if it thinks it has been run and you disagree then you can comment out the body of the migration, run a down with: `bundle exec rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20140523041349`. Then uncomment the body of the migration and re-run the up.

Answer (score 0):

Specify version as an argument (no space around `=`):

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20140523041349
```